# How to use function Recover from ECDSA library?

Tags: solidity, ecdsa

I have an error when trying to use Recover function of ECDSA Library. What is the problem?

[image]

```
import "hardhat/console.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/cryptography/ECDSA.sol";
import "./IToken.sol";
import "./BSCToken.sol";
import "./ETHToken.sol";
import "./TokenBase.sol";

contract Bridge {
    using ECDSA for bytes32;
    address public admin;
    TokenBase public token;
    uint256 public nonce;

    event SwapInitialized(
        address _from,
        address _to,
        uint256 _amount,
        uint256 _chainId,
        uint256 _nonce,
        string _symbol
    );

    constructor(address _token) {
        admin = msg.sender;
        token = TokenBase(_token);
    }

    function swap(
        address _to,
        uint256 _amount,
        uint256 _chainId,
        uint256 _nonce,
        string memory _symbol
    ) external {
        token.burn(msg.sender, _amount);
        emit SwapInitialized(
            msg.sender,
            _to,
            _amount,
            _chainId,
            _nonce,
            _symbol
        );
    }

    function reedem(
        address _to,
        uint256 _amount,
        uint256 _nonce,
        string memory _symbol,
        bytes32 _signatureV,
        bytes32 _signatureR,
        bytes32 _signatureS
    ) external {
        bytes32 signedDataHash = keccak256(
            abi.encodePacked(_to, _amount, _nonce, _symbol)
        );
        bytes32 message = signedDataHash.toEthSignedMessageHash();
        message.recover(_signatureV, _signatureR, _signatureS);
        token.mint(_to, _amount);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for `tryRecover` as `recover` receives the combined signature as input:

```js
message.tryRecover(_signatureV, _signatureR, _signatureS);
```

Edit:
more complete example, using `recover` (not tested)

```
...
    address private _signerAddress = 0x123..;

    function _validSignature(bytes memory signature, bytes32 msgHash) internal view returns (bool) {
        return msgHash.toEthSignedMessageHash().recover(signature) == _signerAddress;
    }

    function reedem(
        address _to,
        uint256 _amount,
        uint256 _nonce,
        string memory _symbol,
        bytes memory signature
    ) external {
        bytes32 msgHash = keccak256(
            abi.encode(_to, _amount, _nonce, _symbol)
        );
        require(_validSignature(signature, msgHash), "INVALID_SIGNATURE");
        // note that this is still not secure, because the nonce
        // is user provided and doesn't change on-chain to signal
        // that it has been used by the user, also replay attacks..
        token.mint(_to, _amount);
    }
```

ethers.js:

```js
  const signature = await signer.signMessage(
    ethers.utils.arrayify(
      ethers.utils.keccak256(
        ethers.utils.defaultAbiCoder.encode(['address', 'uint256', 'uint256', 'string'], [to, amount, nonce, symbol])
      )
    )
  );
```

I want to stress again, that this setup is absolutely not secure.

Comment: the same problem

Comment: _signatureV is supposed to be of type uint8

Comment: It didn't help(

Comment: updated with an example

Comment: Can you tell me how this line works:
`
msgHash.toEthSignedMessageHash().recover(signature)
`
as i know `toEthSignedMessageHash()` takes a parameter of `messageHash` and `recover()` takes mesage hash and signature , u are not passing it in function, how you are doing it?